# Appending query result from a shell script to a csv file

Tags: shell, csv, unix

So I'm querying to get my gps location. 
The shell script command is like this:

```
curl -s http://whatismycountry.com/ | sed -n 's/.*Coordinates \(.*\)<.*/\1/p'
```

Then to save the coordinates to a .csv file I write:

```
curl -s http://whatismycountry.com/ | sed -n 's/.*Coordinates \(.*\)<.*/\1/p' | sed -e 's/.*\[\([^ ]*\) \([^]]*\)\].*/\1,\2/' > cordinates.csv
```

which gives me a csv file with the co-ordinates. 
[the image of the .csv file pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkNdw.png)

Now the query is in a infinite loop and the intent is every time it queries it should save the new coordinates to the next block below.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zWdx.png)

How do I write the regex part in the previous command for that in the script?

Thanks for much help. Totally a noob in regex.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with regex. You should use `>>` for file append instead of `>` which rewrites file every time.

So your command will become

```
curl -s http://whatismycountry.com/ |\ 
sed -n 's/.*Coordinates \(.*\)<.*/\1/p' |\ 
sed -e 's/.*\[\([^ ]*\) \([^]]*\)\].*/\1,\2/' >> cordinates.csv
```

Comment: Thanks .. It was a nice catch .. Missed it completely .. Now it works